# nginx - no ssl for crawlers / bots

Tags: nginx, ssl

In a server directive for port 80 in nginx I want to redirect all requests to https if the user agent is not a bot. I tried using this:

```
...
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent !~* (bot|spider|crawler|sniffer|facebook) ) {
        return 301 https://host.com$request_uri;
    }

    include other-stuff.inc;
}
```

I thought nginx would stop on the `return` but it doesn't. It still processes the `include` (which serves the normal site) and does not redirect. (If I comment the `include` it does the redirect, though). Btw: A `break` also does not work.

Comment: You will probably get a penalty from Google if you do this.

Comment: Why that? Request on :80 and response on :80. No prob. I just want to NOT redirect to https.

Comment: They'll figure out you're serving on https (because someone will link to you) and crawl it anyway. Then you get a duplicate content penalty.

Comment: why? so bot will get http, but user then will be redirected to https? what's the catch?

Comment: You cannot prevent anyone from using `https://example.com` link for linking to your site. So, eventually there will be links both to `https://example.com` and `http://example.com`, which causes duplicate content penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Though some part of the nginx config may resemble the program code, it's actually not. The order is important only for ifs (not always though) and for location matching. So includes aren't aren't parsed by some hypothetical instruction pointer, at least in the case above. This is the reason your include statement works regardless the match.

Comment: Okay and what can I do to stop it after the return? The return just doesn't work if includes follow.

Comment: Depends on what you are including. There are probably some ways to do what you are intending to, but moving `include` around the config isn't going to help.

Comment: These includes are for the normal page to serve. But I want that only when user agent is a bot. If it's not a bot I want a redirect to the ssl page. The corresponding nginx directive has the same includes.

Comment: It might not be possible to do this in nginx, you might need to do this in your application.